# chrome notifications reset by button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I am working on a web app.

I am using chrome notifications that are switched on once chrome asks for permissions. 
Once Notification.permission is granted, The button switches to on.

What I want to do is switch off this button, and - as a result of this - also switch the dektop notifications or at least re-prompt the notification alert.

Here is my code

```
$scope.desktopNotificationSettings=function(){

    // If browser doesnt support notifications
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }

    // This is entered if permission is already there and button is triggered :: That means user wants to switch of desktop notifications
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        console.log("Entered granted");
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission){
                if (('permission' in Notification)) {
                    console.log(permission);
                    Notification.permission = denied;
                }
            });
        this.allowDesktopNotification = false;
        return;
    }
    // This triggers a chrome alert to block or allow notifications
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            console.log("Entered denied");
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission){
                if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                    Notification.permission = permission;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Now if the permission is denied then request permission works fine for the first time.
If I click on the button it doesn't trigger the permission alert in chrome.

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Are you using AngularJS here? You should add that to your tags.